# How to make my cart quantity counter to stop at 1?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to make my cart quantity counter to stop at 1?

I want to make the quantity counter in my cart class to stop at 1 when it is decreased, and not go down to 0 or negative values. Currently it counts any number from -n to +n, but I want it to stop at 1 when it is decreased.

The cart class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'dish_object.dart';

class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Dish> _cart;
  Cart(this._cart);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState(this._cart);
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  _CartState(this._cart);

  List<Dish> _cart;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[100],
        title: Text(
          'Cart',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send_rounded),
              tooltip: "Confirm Order",
              onPressed: () {
                if (_cart.isNotEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Order Confirmed",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green[200],
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
                if (_cart.isEmpty) {
                  setState(() {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: "Cart Empty",
                        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                        gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                        timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0);
                  });
                }
              }),
          if (_cart.length > 0)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, bottom: 10.0),
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 10.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: Text(
                  _cart.length.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 12.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _cart.length + 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          if (index == _cart.length)
            return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 2.0),
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  ),
                  elevation: 4.0,
                  child: Text(
                      "Cart Total: R" +
                          _cart
                              .fold<int>(0, (a, b) => a + b.totalPrice())
                              .toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          fontSize: 25,
                          color: Colors.redAccent[200])),
                ),
              ),
            );
          var item = _cart[index];
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 1.0),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 4.0,
              child: ListTile(
                //Leading
                leading: Text(
                  item.category + "\n" + "R" + item.price.toString(),
                ),

                //Title
                title: Text(item.brandName +
                    "\n" +
                    "(" +
                    item.counter.toString() +
                    ")"),
                //Subtitle
                subtitle: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.incrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),

                //Trailing
                trailing: GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.remove_circle,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      item.decrementCounter();
                    });
                  },
                ),
                isThreeLine: true,
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The dish class containing the increment/decrement functions

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Dish {
  final String category;
  final String brandName;
  final int price;
  int counter = 1;

  int sum;

  int totalPrice() {
    return sum = price * counter;
  }

  void decrementCounter() {
    counter--;
  }

  void incrementCounter() {
    counter++;
  }

  Dish({this.category, this.brandName, this.price});
}
```

Comment: did you try if(counter > 1) { counter--; } in your decrementCounter?